# Google organic results localization

Tags: localization, seo

I am managing a big website which is localized for 9 languages.

But when you google it the first result is always a main page *xxx.com/* with english description - no matter what Google (e.g. *google.de*, *google.es*) site is used.

I intend to change this situation to present dedicated localized link - e.g. if *google.**de*** was used - the first result should be linked to *xxx.com/**de**/* with German description.

Apple accomplished it:

[image: Apple in google.de amd google.es]

So, how to do this?

My only idea is to disable in *robots.txt* the main page *xxx.com/* which is always first in results no matter which *google.XX* was used. Then only *xxx.com/lang-tag* would be used and maybe Google will show appropriate lang-tag to current language. But I am afraid it is not a good way.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, similar questions should be asked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a separate sitemap for each language/subfolder. You can then specify the subfolder as a site in Google Webmaster tools.

If you look at Apple, you see this:

http://www.apple.com/sitemap/

http://www.apple.com/fr/sitemap/

.. and so on. You can then set the geotargeting within GWT once you have verified the site. If you need help with anything let me know.

Comment: Thanks, apparently this a good workaround because I visited Google yesterday and they proposed the same workaround :)